# Trying to call a stored procedure in my ASP.NET project using Entity Framework Core

Tags: stored-procedures, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am creating a REST API and need to call a stored procedure with one or more parameters. I thought I could use this

```
var result = _dbContext.SqlQuery<string>(sql, someParamSqlParameter).ToList();
```

But I get an error that says

> No Overload Method for SqlQuery takes 2 arguments

Here is my code

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>>> GetCompanyName(string param)
{
    var symbolParameter = new SqlParameter("@TickerSymbol", param);
         
    var symbol= _dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<string>("p_GetCompanyInfo @TickerSymbol", symbolParameter).ToList();
}
```

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Packages installed:

```
EntityFrameworkCore 7.0.10
EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 7.0.10
EntityFrameworkCore.Tools 7.0.10
```

UPDATE:
I am still unable to get this to work.  Same error that it does not take two parameters

````
    [ApiController]
    public class QuickPicksController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly QuickPicssContext _dbContext;
        public QuickPicksController(QuickPicssContext dbContext)
        {
            _dbContext = dbContext; 
        }

        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>>> GetStockDefs(int id)
        {
            //Get a list of stocks by security types
           // var stockList = _dbContext.QwikPikSymbols.Where(s => s.SecurityType == id).Select(s => s.Symbol);

          //  if (stockList.IsNullOrEmpty()) return NotFound();

            //return await stockList.ToListAsync();

            return _dbContext.QwikPikSymbols.FromSql("EXECUTE Customers_SearchCustomers @ContactName", "TEST").ToList();

        }


    }```
````

Comment: Have you had a look at https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/working-with-stored-procedure-in-ef-core.aspx ?

Comment: This was extremley useful.  I read through the whole thing.  Going to give it a try today

Comment: Still having an issue with this. Posting my new code now

Comment: Please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.

Comment: Please read the actual documentation. https://learn.microsoft.com/ef/core/querying/sql-queries

Comment: Ian thank you. Got it now.

Answer (score 0):

There are some little changes when using the EF core packages of your version, that’s why you got the error.

[official code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LAlqy.png)

As you can see in the official code, you cannot give two arguments to FromSql(), it only needs the sql argument, you need to pass the parameter in the sql.

If you want to call stored procedure with one or more parameters, you can get your stored procedures like this:

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public IActionResult GetStockDefs([FromQuery]int id, [FromQuery]string title)
{
    Console.WriteLine(id);
    //FROMSQL
    var IdParameter = new SqlParameter("@param1",id);
    var TitleParameter = new SqlParameter("@param2", title);
    var ids = _context.Demo.FromSql($"EXECUTE dbo.SelfProcedure @param1={IdParameter},@param2={TitleParameter}").ToList();
    for (int i = 0; i < ids.Count; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ids[i].Title);
    }
    return View();
}
```

As you can see the calling of stored procedure

[url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWra5.png)

[log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/geXuk.png)

Also you can use FromSqlRaw

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public IActionResult GetStockDefs([FromQuery]int id, [FromQuery]string title)
{
    Console.WriteLine(id);
    //FROMSQLRAW
    var IdParameter = new SqlParameter("@param1", SqlDbType.Int) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Input, Value = id };
    var TitleParameter = new SqlParameter("@param2", SqlDbType.NVarChar) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Input, Value = title };
    var ids = _context.Demo.FromSqlRaw("EXECUTE dbo.SelfProcedure @param1,@param2",IdParameter,TitleParameter).ToList();
    for (int i = 0; i < ids.Count; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ids[i].Title);
    }
    return View();
}
```

[log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkOmx.png)